# Macro message and Document Information panel error popup's on server

Tags: 2007, configuration

We use Moss 2007.
We have documents in a page where we can create documents on the server.
While creating new document, after Microsoft word gets opened, a pop up is showing up for all users

> The macros in this project are disabled. please refer to the online
>   help or documentation of the host application to determine how to
>   enable macros.

How to enable the Macros so the popup doesn't show up?.

Also when trying to save the following popup shows up

> The file cannot be saved because some properties are missing or
>   invalid use the Document information panel to provide the correct
>   property values. Errors for required properties are marked with a red
>   asterisk, and errors for invalid properties are marked with a red
>   dashed border.

When filling the information panel like approver name and click on Find it says

> This action cannot be performed for untrusted sites. To use Find you
>   must add this site to the list of trusted sites for your web browser

But, the site is already added to the trusted sites in the browser

Again after filling the document information panel while trying to save on the server, shows pop up

> This file has missing or invalid properties that are not displayed in
>   the current document information panel view. To locate the missing or
>   invalid properties,  click the arrow next to properties in the
>   document information panel and select a different view

Any suggestion on where can I disable the Macros popup and how to know the missing or invalid properties of the word document?

Comment: Can you try to reset your security zones and try again?

Comment: where can I reset the security zones?

Comment: (IE Menu Bar) Tools -> Options -> Security Tab -> Reset all zones to default level.

Comment: Its the same even after Reset

Comment: Is your sharepoint site in the trusted list of sites in IE?

Comment: I have added it to the trusted list, and I am able to submit the Document after filling the required fields in Document Information panel. However the 1st message "The macros in this project are disabled" is still coming. Any procedure where I can disable the message without it popping out everytime?

Comment: That's a problem with the file you have. That isn't a SharePoint issue, but here is what i got just by googling, http://www.informationmapping.com/us/software-support/fs-pro-knowledge-base/troubleshooting/the-macros-have-been-disabled